# Remove Hyper V in Azure Virtual Machine Windows Server 2012

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, azure

I would like to know how to disable or remove Hyper V in virtual machine that's running on Windows Server 2012 in Azure.

When I check the Status, it seems to be disabled. However, when I try to install HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager) the following message pops up:

- VT not supported error:

[image: VT-not-supported-error]

- Hyper-V option shows disabled:

[image]

Comment: Are you positive your machine supports VT-x.  Instead of submiting a comment, or submitting an answer, edit your original question and include this vital information.  Only by providing this vital information can your question be answered.

Comment: You're running in a Hyper-V VM.  Hyper-V has very limited nesting abilities, which goes along with not fully passing through all CPU features.  What you're seeing is expected, as VT-X is not, by default, passed through to a VM.

Answer (score -1):

Nested virtualization in Azure is only supported on a limited set of virtual machines. For a complete list of vm types that support nesting, please take a look at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/acu (virtual machines that support nesting are marked with ***)